# How to manipulate a select options based on another select option in html?

Tags: javascript, html, select, dropdown

I have two select tags (both are same) :

```
<select class="form-control" name='end'>
    <option selected disabled hidden value="">end</option>

    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
</select>
```

Here, if I select one option from first dropdown , then in second dropdown all option up to the selected one should not be shown. For example,
If I select 5 in first dropdown then second dropdown should show only 6-11.
Can anyone help me with this?

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/k9gvxp54/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to associate a change event listener to the select dropdown with name `start` so that when each option is selected from this dropdown you can `show/hide` the `option` in `end` dropdown like this. Also, make note of `parseInt()` which will compare the `option` value as a integer and give you the correct result.

```js
$('select[name="start"]').change(function(){
  var selectedValue = parseInt($(this).val());
  changeEndOptions(selectedValue);
});

function changeEndOptions(startValue){
  var $options = $('select[name="end"] option');
  $options.each(function(){
    var optionVal = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(optionVal <= startValue){
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name='start'>
    <option selected disabled hidden value="">start</option>

    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>

</select>


<select class="form-control" name='end'>
    <option selected disabled hidden value="">end</option>

   
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @qwww You can further modify the code to use `parseInt()`. check the updated answer. That works now.

Comment: but why there is "end" in second dropdown?

Comment: Do you need both the select with name="start" and text label as "start"?

Comment: I assumed you need to have one select as start and another as end so that the end dropdown option depend on start option @qwww

Comment: no i dont need that "end" inside second dropdown...both dropdowns with numbers only

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an onchange event listener, and use the value of the first select to loop through the second select and hide the options.

Using jQuery:

```
var max = 0;
var options = $("select[name='end']").find('option');

$("select[name='start']").on('change', function() {

    options.each(function(){
        $(this).show();
    });

    max = parseInt( $(this).val() );

    for (i=0; i < max; i++) {
        $(options[i]).hide();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

give ids to your selects, for example: `#firstSelect` and `#secondSelect`
I made this solution using **jquery** because it is simpler than with plain javascript. Try this:

```
 $("#firstSelect").change(function () {
      var selectedOption = $("select option:selected").text();
      $("#secondSelect option").each(function() {
        var txtOption = $(this).text();
        if(parseInt(txtOption) <= parseInt(selectedOption)){ 
          $(this).remove();
        }
      });
});
```

---

If you want this to work more than once, so that when you change the first one again the second one changes again and adds or remove the options fresh from the begining:

```
$("#firstSelect").change(function () {
    var selectedOption = $("select option:selected").text();
    $("#secondSelect").empty();
    for (var index = 2; index < 12; index++) {
        if(index >= parseInt(selectedOption)){
            $("#secondSelect").append(
                $('<option></option>').html(index)
            );
        }
    }
});
```

check the indexes in the for loop, these are hardcoded from 2 to 12. You could do that dinamically aswell. But if there are always the options 1,2,3...9,10 in the first dropdown, this should work fine.